# Jump to first page on clicking "new" on new navigation

Tags: bug, new-nav

On the old navigation, clicking the <kbd>newest</kbd> tab, will send me back to the first page. I see this as the natural behavior, to see new changes where they normally occur.

On the new navigation, when I click <kbd>new</kbd> and I'm on the second page or so, I will remain on the page I was before, usually not seeing any updates.

Was this changed intentionally? So far, the above tab click, was the only convenient way, to preserve my custom tags setting; but I have to set the page at the bottom to move back to the front. Otherwise, clicking <kbd>Questions</kbd>  does move me back, but I lose my settings.

**Most astonishing**, changing tabs (to - say - "need answer") the page also remains the same and won't jump to the front. This is really weird, if I may say.

My home tab is "new", use custom tags, and sorted to "newest", but it happens to all tabs and sorts.

---

EDIT: Just noticed, I could use the new "permalink". It *will* move me to the front. But it just behaves like reloading the page by the browser, which also moves me to the front.

Comment: can you add the screenshot? or tell what's your sort option is set to? is it "recently active" or "newest"

Comment: Thanks for the edit... I just reproduced it.... You do have a point here... I moved 4 pages for my custom tag and I see "new" tab is set (hover over link)  to the same page I go to... The only way I can go to "main page" is either you click on the "Questions" tab or "META" logo. But, then it takes your "custom tag" settings.... Definitely something strange thing happening here. +1

Comment: that's because "Permalink" remained same on all the pages you navigated ... what if the permalink gets fixed...

Comment: no problem lets go where?.... send me link